# Unexpected symmetric test result using (arr.transpose() == arr).all()

Tags: python, numpy, symmetric

I have

```
temp = np.power(np.sum(S,1),-0.5)
S_hat = np.diagflat(temp).dot(S).dot(np.diagflat(temp))
```

The symmetric test for `S` yields `True` but for `S_hat`, returns `False`. I can't wrap my heads around this one.

[EDIT] S and data are defined as follows:

```
from math import pi

def make_moons(n):
    """Create a 'two moons' dataset with n feature vectors, 
        and 2 features per vector."""

    assert n%2==0, 'n must be even'
    # create upper moon
    theta = np.linspace(-pi / 2, pi / 2, n/2)
    # create lower moon
    x = np.r_[np.sin(theta) - pi / 4, np.sin(theta)]
    y = np.r_[np.cos(theta), -np.cos(theta) + .5]
    data = np.c_[x, y]
    # Add some noise
    data = data + 0.03 * np.random.standard_normal(data.shape)

    # create labels
    labels = np.r_[np.ones((n//2, 1)), -np.ones((n//2, 1))]
    labels = labels.ravel().astype(np.int32)

    return data,labels

S = np.zeros((100,100));
sig = 0.09;
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform, cdist
B = pdist(data);
C = squareform(B);
S = np.exp(-C/sig);
```

Comment: What is `S`? Can you explain what the test is supposed to test? Is it possible to have an example of input data?

Comment: @AGNGazer: I've edited the post to include S. As for the caption, I just meant it as a representation. I'm talking about the test in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are seeing rounding errors. Instead of strict equality test, try using [`numpy.allclose()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html):

```
np.allclose(S_hat.T, S_hat, rtol=1e-7, atol=1e-8)
```

Adjust tolerances according to your specific data magnitudes. In particular, for your example data, it seems like `atol` should be set to 0 (your data range from 1 to 1e-14).